# add additional column to base kubectl get pods command

Tags: kubectl

im trying to build a custom column query that we use all the time.  what i want is to take this basic output:

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mypod                              2/2     Running   4          2d3h
```

and simply add a column to it, all i want is to add `NODE:.spec.nodeName` to this table.  I can't find the base column format for the above, does anyone know where i can find it?  I tried searching in the kubectl source code, but that proved to be a bit of a challenge.

Where can i find this output pattern?

Comment: I don't have a solution to your particular question but adding `-o wide` will show the node name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604805/how-can-get-ready-status-restarts-age-etc-in-kubectl-as-custom-columns has some helpful details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tag `--custom-columns` in kubectl command to get the nodeName:

> `-o=custom-columns=<spec>`    Print a table using a comma separated list of custom columns

For example:

`kubectl get pods my-pod -o=custom-columns='DATA:spec.nodeName'` will return the node name.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#formatting-output) you can find more about the tag and see usage examples.

Comment: He wants to *add* a column. -o forces you to declare each column you want. It's not additive.